# What is the purpose of passing "globals()" as web.py fvars?

Tags: web.py

[`web.application`](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/api#web.application) accepts an undocumented `fvars` argument to which the [web.py tutorial](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial) passes `globals()` like so:

```
import web

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello, world!"

urls = (
  '/', 'index'
)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
```

I've seen at least one application that passes `locals()`.  What is this variable used for, and why would you want to pass it `locals()` or `globals()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's used by `application.handle()` (which in turn calls `application._delegate()`) to convert the handler class from a string to the class object itself. [Source code here.](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/application.py#L461)

For example, in your code snippet above, `urls = ('/', 'index')` is the URL-to-class-string mapping. So `web.application` needs your `globals()` dict to be able to look up the string `'index'` and get the class itself.

I actually think this is a somewhat non-Pythonic design. Why not just pass in the class directly? I think web.py supports that approach too. However, I believe the classes were done as strings so autoreload is simpler. The autoreload code uses `fvars` heavily.

Re `locals()`: at the module level, `locals()` doesn't really make sense, but it returns the same dictionary as `globals()`, which is why that would work.

Comment: This seems like a sensible explanation.  However, the lookup seems really weird to me; if you pass a fully-qualified class name, why would you pass a dictionary in addition?  Maybe it supports both cases (e.g. local names and a dict OR fully qualified names and an empty dict).

Comment: @AndréCaron, web.py has to be able to look up the class name somewhere, hence the globals dictionary. It can't look up the class name in its own globals, it needs your app's.

Comment: Sure it can, it just needs to resolve the dotted name like other Python frameworks.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know how they do that?

Comment: Basically: split the string at the last period, then use `__import__()` to do something like "from x.y import z".  There's probably a number of edge cases you may want to handle.  Take a look at Pyramid's [dotted name resolver](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/api/path.html#pyramid.path.DottedNameResolver).  The source code is somewhere on Github.